# How to remove items within embedded documents list using Where/In clause

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

Want to remove items from HomeTimeline which exist in another list (unfollowedUserHomeTimelineIds) while I update the User object with a couple of more things.

```
var update = Builders<User>.Update
    .Inc(u => u.FollowingCount, -1)
    .PullFilter(p => p.Following, f => f.Id == unfollowedUserObjectId)
    .PullFilter(p => p.HomeTimeline, Builders<Reference>.Filter.In(r => r.Id, unfollowedUserHomeTimelineIds));
var result = Users.UpdateOneAsync(p => p.Id == myUserObjectId, update).Result;
```

the above is resulting in:

```
MongoCommandException: Command update failed: Operator ''OPERATOR_PULL' with condition' is not supported.
```

any ideas?

Comment: Hint: Use shell syntax. I have no idea of C#, nor do I plan to change that. I guess that is valid for quite some MongoDB specialists. But the error message pretty much says it all.